# emacs org-mode exporting to iCalendar format problem

Tags: emacs, export, icalendar, org-mode

I have just started to use Emacs and org-mode. I am using emacs (version 26.3) on mac.

I want to create items in org-mode that are scheduled and export them to iCalendar format so that I can import them to Calendar app. Here is org file `caltest.org`.

```
* test calendar
** meeting x
    SCHEDULED: <2020-01-16 Thu 12:15-14:00>
   :PROPERTIES:
   :LOCATION: room 1
   :END:
** TODO meeting y
    SCHEDULED: <2020-01-15 Wed>
   :PROPERTIES:
   :LOCATION: room 2
   :END:
```

When I export (C-c C-e c f) file to iCalendar format. I get the following file generated `caltest.ics` with this content:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
X-WR-CALNAME:caltest
PRODID:-//Mario Kusek//Emacs with Org mode//EN
X-WR-TIMEZONE:CET
X-WR-CALDESC:
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
END:VCALENDAR
```

As you can see there are no events in the file.

I am using `org-plus-contrib-20191230` for org-mode. This is the latest version. I don't know if there are some logs which I can inspect or how to debug exporting.

What am I doing wrong and how can I inspect exporting?

Comment: [`SCHEDULED:` does not mean what you think it means](https://orgmode.org/manual/Deadlines-and-Scheduling.html#Deadlines-and-Scheduling): try exporting the document after deleting it - just leave the timestamp.

Comment: When I removed SCHEDULED: it is now exporting it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but you can customize the variable

```
org-icalendar-use-scheduled
```

to specify precisely when you want an event created if SCHEDULED is present